# pandas: merge with a key in different columns (merge using col1 OR col2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

`df_a` and `df_b` are two dataframes that looks like following. They do NOT have same length.

```
--> df_a
col_1  col_2
a      b
c
d
       e
f      g

--> df_b
col_3
a
c
d
e
```

I know I can achieve a merge with AND clause with :

```py
df_a = pd.Dataframe({"col_1": ["a", "c", "d", None, "f"], "col_2": ["b", None, None, "e", "g"]})
df_b = pd.Dataframe({"col_3": ["a", "c", "d", "e"]})

pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how="inner", left_on=["col_1", "col_2"], right_on=["col_3", "col_3"])
```

My need is to merged them based on a OR clause like `col_1 == col_3 OR col_2 == col_3`. Ideally I do not want to make two merges separately.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please vote reopen as the associated question does NOT answer my question : there is no common column between dataframes like `full_add` in associated question.

Comment: please add sample output as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double left `merge`, first with 'col_1', then with 'col_2' and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) the two outputs:

```
(df_a
 .merge(df_b, left_on='col_1', right_on='col_3', how='left')
 .combine_first(df_a.merge(df_b, left_on='col_2', right_on='col_3', how='left'))
)
```

output:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3  col_4
0     a     b     a    0.0
1     c  None     c    1.0
2     d  None     d    2.0
3  None     e     e    3.0
4     f     g   NaN    NaN
```

used input (with extra column):

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": ["a", "c", "d", None, "f"],
                     "col_2": ["b", None, None, "e", "g"]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"col_3": ["a", "c", "d", "e"], "col_4": range(4)})
```

###### arbitrary number of columns

you can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and a list of columns in order of the preferred match (modified input to see the difference, here 'col_2' has priority over 'col_1'):

```
cols = ['col_2', 'col_1']

from functools import reduce

out = reduce(lambda a,b: a.combine_first(b),
             [df_a.merge(df_b, left_on=c, right_on='col_3', how='left')
              for c in cols])
```

output:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3  col_4
0     a     c     c    1.0
1     c  None     c    1.0
2     d  None     d    2.0
3  None     e     e    3.0
4     f     g   NaN    NaN
```

modified input:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": ["a", "c", "d", None, "f"],
                     "col_2": ["c", None, None, "e", "g"]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"col_3": ["a", "c", "d", "e"], "col_4": range(4)})
```